# jQuery unclosable modal not respecting options

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

In my application I am using jQuery 1.12.3 and some modal.

I'd like to set one modal in particular to "unclosable", so if you click outside the modal it won't close and if you hit Esc on the keyboard it won't close.

Looking at the modal options, there is closeOnEscape and closeOnClick which should be what I am looking for, but when opening the modal with those two options set to false, the modal behaves like those options weren't set.

```
jQuery( '#myModal' ).openModal({ closeOnClick: false,
              closeOnEscape: false});
```

This modal in particular is as follows:

```
<div id="infoModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p id="textForModal"></p>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn-flat"><spring:message code="OK"/></a>
                <a href="#!" class=" modal-startTimer modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn-flat"><spring:message code="Continue"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something else? Unfortunately I can't make the jump to the latest jQuery as it will break my app.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a link to this **some modal** of yours?

Comment: Added an example of modal in the question!

Comment: i mean i link to the modal library man how are we suppose quess the modal library are you are using?

Comment: For the love of everything holy, upgrade to the latest jquery. 1.12.3 is shamefully outdated